# Sprockets::FileNotFound in Projects#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I cloned this [project](https://github.com/catarse/catarse) . Then i ran `docker-compose up` and navigated to `localhost:300` and got `Sprockets::FileNotFound in Projects#index` error. Do I have to do `bower install` in the host os? Is there a way to do that without having to install node or ruby in the host os? I do not want to pollute my host os thats why i chose docker for my dev environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the concept of docker so I was reluctant to install anything in my host os. Turns out that I had to install bower to get rid of the issue